# How to add one hour repeately from start time till to next day start time using panda python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, time

Here I have a csv file with data . I want to write a code that  start time start from csv file time column first time and it will be equal as 0. Then from that time add one hour one hour till to next day start time. Then after that again that time become as 0 and add one hour one hour till to next day start time . This process continue.

```
time_interval = 3600 (in seconds)
date_array = []
date_array.append(pd.to_datetime(data['date'][0]).date())
start_time = []
end_time   = []
temp_date  = pd.to_datetime(data['date'][0]).date()
start_time=0
for i in range(len(data['date'])):
 cur_date = pd.to_datetime(data['date'][i]).date()
 if( cur_date > temp_date):
    end_time.append(pd.to_datetime(data['time'][i-1], format='%H:%M:%S').time())
    start_time=0
    date_array.append(cur_date)
    temp_date = cur_date
end_time.append(pd.to_datetime(data['time'][len(data['date'])-1], format='%H:%M:%S').time())
datetime_array = []
for i in range(len(date_array)):
  s_time = start_time
  e_time = datetime.datetime.combine(date_array[i],  end_time[i])
print(datetime_array)
```

I didn't get answer that I want. 
Here I include my csv file.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add sample input data to the question please?

Comment: What are input data? Only one row? Or only first time row for each day? Do you need end each day in 23:00 ? Or in 10:00, custom time?

Comment: @Rakesh I upload again my csv file. I hope you can understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @jezrael I upload new csv file. I hope you can understand what I am trying to do. Yes I need end each day at 23:59:59. My start time will be custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create new column filled by datetimes, then get first value per days with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for subtract with datetimes, last convert timedeltas by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and then to minutes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date':['10/3/2018'] * 5 + ['10/4/2018'],
        'time':['6:00:00','7:00:00','8:00:00','9:00:00','10:00:00','6:00:00'],
        'col':[4,8,9,4,2,3],

})

df['datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['time'], format='%d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S')
first = df.groupby('date')['datetime'].transform('first')
df['new'] = df['datetime'].sub(first).dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int)
print (df)

        date      time  col            datetime  new
0  10/3/2018   6:00:00    4 2018-03-10 06:00:00    0
1  10/3/2018   7:00:00    8 2018-03-10 07:00:00   60
2  10/3/2018   8:00:00    9 2018-03-10 08:00:00  120
3  10/3/2018   9:00:00    4 2018-03-10 09:00:00  180
4  10/3/2018  10:00:00    2 2018-03-10 10:00:00  240
5  10/4/2018   6:00:00    3 2018-04-10 06:00:00    0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (first)
0   2018-03-10 06:00:00
1   2018-03-10 06:00:00
2   2018-03-10 06:00:00
3   2018-03-10 06:00:00
4   2018-03-10 06:00:00
5   2018-04-10 06:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I had large dataset then How I can read the csv file with time and date. Dataframe will be long. Can you suggest me an option for this. Then I have to write it in for loop i range.

Comment: @awa - You can use `df = pd.read_csv(file)` for convert file to DataFrame - [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. You save my day.

Comment: I have another question. I upload another pic of csv file to understand the question to you that I am going to do. according to the second image assume my start time at 10:00:00 then it is ==0. after that my second time is 11:15:00 I want to mention it as 120min. after that my third time is 12:00:00 , then it will be 180min , my fourth time 14:00:00 then it will be 240min. So can we write a code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["10/3/2018"],
["10/3/2018"],
["10/3/2018"],
["10/3/2018"],
["10/3/2018"],
["10/3/2018"],
["10/4/2018"],
["10/4/2018"],
["10/4/2018"],
["10/4/2018"],
],columns=['date'])

df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
start_time = '6:00:00'
df.loc[:,'time'] = start_time
increment = df.groupby(['date', 'time']).cumcount().astype('timedelta64[h]')
df.loc[:,'time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.loc[:,'time'])
df['time'] =  df['time'] + increment
```

Output

```
        date     time
0 2018-03-10 06:00:00
1 2018-03-10 07:00:00
2 2018-03-10 08:00:00
3 2018-03-10 09:00:00
4 2018-03-10 10:00:00
5 2018-03-10 11:00:00
6 2018-04-10 06:00:00
7 2018-04-10 07:00:00
8 2018-04-10 08:00:00
9 2018-04-10 09:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But this is not I am looking for actually. Here I upload the new csv file. Hope you will understand it.